# Como eu pego um dado em uma página e coloco em outra?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso pegar um dado enviado pelo usuário através do método GET em uma página, colocar esse dado no banco de dados e, em outra página, preciso ler esse dado do banco de dados e escrever na página. No caso, eu tenho uma tabela chamada `comandos` onde tenho dua colunas `nome` e `valor` e quero pegar o dado do campo `valor`que está na mesma linha onde o campo `nome` contem o valor `LED1`

Tentei isso, mas não funcionou:

**Página 1**

```
mysql_connect("u541106066_estad","u541106066_ctp","jkf45s6f4sdf4");
$sSQL="Update comandos Set valor='$_GET_["LED1"]' Where nome='LED1'";
mysql_db_query("u541106066_estad",$sSQL);
```

**Página 2**

```
mysql_connect("u541106066_estad","u541106066_ctp","81GDYC2lDC");
$sql = 'SELECT valor FROM comandos';
echo "led=$ql";
```

Comment: Faltou executar a sql.

Comment: como assim ? Poderia exemplificar

Comment: Fiz um exemplo pra ti Carlos, dá uma olhada... com a execução e o fetch_array()

Comment: Outra coisa, qual é o aspecto temporal desse dado?
Ele deve ser gravado em banco de dados relacional mesmo?

Sessão não serve?

Comment: Está dando erro no primeiro código. Não tenho muito conhecimento em my sql. O que preciso exatamente é colocar um dado em uma página e dar saída em outra página. Essas páginas vão ser acessadas de clientes diferentes. Um vai enviar o dado e o outro vai pegar. O dado em questão deve ser mantindo mesmo quando os clientes se desconectarem. Esse processo deve acontecer em tempo real e continuamente.

Comment: Hora de migrar para o PDO :)

Comment: Para fazer `SELECT` você tem que usar a função [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#example-1622), no exemplo você está apenas imprimindo o valor da query, está assim no código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você deseja me parece muito simples, você pode fazer isso desta maneira:

1. Crie uma classe (arquivo: Database.php) para acessar o banco de dados utilizando PDO, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Database {

 private static $servidor = 'localhost'; // Servidor, no caso poderia ser também localhost
 private static $usuario = 'u541106066_ctp'; // usuário do banco de dados
 private static $senha = 'jkf45s6f4sdf4'; // senha do banco de dados
 private static $banco = 'u541106066_estad'; // nome do banco de dados
 private static $instance = null;

 //inicia a conexão
  public static function getConnection() {
     if (!self::$instance instanceof PDO) {
         try {
             self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . 
             self::$servidor . ';dbname=' . 
             self::$banco, 
             self::$usuario, 
             self::$senha, 
             array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
         } catch (PDOException $exc) {
           echo "Erro ao conectar :: {$exc->getMessage()}";
         }
     } 
  return self::$instance;
  }

//metodo para trazer vários resultados
  public function fetchAll($query) {
     $con = self::getConnection();
     $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
     $this->execute($stmt);

     if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
     } else {
       return false;
     }
  }

//metodo para trazer um resultado
 public function fetch($query) {
    $con = self::getConnection();
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $this->execute($stmt);

    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
         return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }

 //executa o PDO
  public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null) {
     try {
           if (isset($data)) {
               $stmt->execute($data);
           } else {
           $stmt->execute();
           }
     } catch (PDOException $exc) {
       echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
       var_dump($exc->getMessage());
     }
  }

 //metodo para inserir e atualizar dados
  public function save($sql, array $data) {

     $con = self::getConnection();
     $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
     $this->execute($stmt, $data);

     if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
        return true;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
  }

}
```

2. Utilize a classe para pegar os dados do banco, crie um arquivo do tipo index.php e neste arquivo faça o seguinte:

```
//primeiro você precisa incluir a classe
require_once("Database.php");

//agora você precisa instanciá-la:
$conexao = new Database();

/*
Agora basta chamar o método para a query que você quer buscar no seu banco, através da requisição GET.
- no seu caso /index.php?id=1
- Armazene numa variável o valor que receber
*/
$requisicao_consulta = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
//para post, salva a id no campo hidden 
$valor_id = ($_POST['id'] != '') ? $_POST['id'] : null;
//requisição de inclusão/atualização
$requisicao_save = (isset($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : null;

if ($requisicao_save != null) {

    $values = [
       'id' => $valor_id,
       'val1' => $_POST['valor1'],
       'val2' => $_POST['valor2'],
       'val3' => $_POST['valor3'],
    ];

} else {

    if ($requisicao_consulta != null) {
        $data = $conexao->fetch("SELECT id,
                                        valor1,
                                        valor2,
                                        valor3 
                                 FROM   comandos
                                 WHERE  id='$requisicao_consulta'");
    }

    $message = "- Preencha o formulário abaixo:\n<br>";

    if (isset($_GET['success-insert'])) {
       $message .= "Dados cadastrados com sucesso!\n<br>";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['success-update'])) {
       $message .= "Dados atualizados com sucesso!\n<br>";
    }
}

//agora basta chamar a query com a requisição

if ($requisicao_save == 'insert' && $valor_id == null) {
   $execute = $conexao->save("INSERT INTO comandos
                              (id, valor1, valor2, valor3)
                              VALUES (:id,:val1,:val2,:val3);",
                              $values);
   header('Location: index.php?success-insert');
}

if ($requisicao_save == 'update' && $valor_id != null) {
   $execute = $conexao->save("UPDATE comandos SET
                              valor1=:val1,
                              valor2=:val2,
                              valor3=:val3
                              WHERE id:id;",
                              $values);
  header('Location: index.php?success-update');
}

//a variável $data representa os dados (em objeto) que contém o conjunto de valores trazido pela similaridade da sua requisição, como não é uma coleção, "não" utilizamos $conexao->fetchAll("..."), onde teríamos uma coleção em array. Desta maneira, vamos construir um formulário para preencher os dados que serão alterados (vou escrever em php mesmo, depois você refatora se achar melhor):  

$inputs = [];

$action = 'insert';

if (!empty($data)) {

    $action = 'update';
    foreach ($data as $key => $dado) {
    $inputs["<label>{ucwords($key)}</label>\n<input type=\"text\" value=\"{$dado->$key}\" name=\"{$key}\">"];
    }

    $inputs["<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"update\">"];

} else {

    for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $inputs["<label>Valor {$i}</label>\n<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" name=\"valor{$i}\">"];
    }

}
$inputs["<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"{$action}\">"];
$inputs["<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"{$valor_id}\">"];
$inputs["<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Salvar\">"];
echo "<div id=\"mensagem\" class=\"msg\">{$message}</div>\n";
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}\" name=\"send\" id=\"send\">\n";
echo implode("\n<br />", $inputs);
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Na página 2, faz assim:

```
$res = mysql_db_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['valor'];
}
```

Comment: Também sugeri isso, porém, ele está usando o PDO. O que não dá pra fazer desta nossa forma.